# exam class : question with circles of same size

Tags: tikz-styles, exam

Using code mentioned below : i'm able to circle question numbers :

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt, text=white] (char) {#1};}}
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\circled{\thequestion}}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[4] Choose the correct reponse: 
\begin{choices} \choice Option A
\choice Option B
\choice Option C
\choice Option D
 \end{choices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

But as question number increases from one digit to two digit number, circle size changes.

[image]

Can you suggest how can we've circle of constant size for all numbers.
[1-100]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Give the node for the circled number a `minimum size` like in this approach.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]
    \node[
      shape=circle,
      fill,
      inner sep=1.5pt,
      text=white,
      minimum size=1.5em
    ] (char) {#1};
}

\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\circled{\thequestion}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}
    \setcounter{question}{8}  % only to show the effect

    \question[4] Choose the correct reponse:
    \begin{choices} \choice Option A
      \choice Option B
      \choice Option C
      \choice Option D
    \end{choices}

    \question[4] Choose the correct reponse:
    \begin{choices} \choice Option A
      \choice Option B
      \choice Option C
      \choice Option D
    \end{choices}

    \question[4] Choose the correct reponse:
    \begin{choices} \choice Option A
      \choice Option B
      \choice Option C
      \choice Option D
    \end{choices}
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to specify the minimum size as, for example, "whatever the width of 30" is, or "whatever the width of 100" is?

Comment: @mrc: If I understand you right, you may replace `1.5em` with `\widthof{30}` or `\widthof{100}`, respectively.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig Thank You, it's working perfectly